# Can SpaCy produce alternative possible dependency trees for a given sentence?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, spacy

I'm trying out [SpaCy](https://spacy.io) NLP for the first time and it seems to have high accuracy when determining the sentence structure.  Obviously it is not always correct, for example when the grammar is ambiguous (75 to 85% correct in my experiments).

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Example 1 - finds incorrect dependency tree
sent = "unlock door with the key"
doc = nlp(sent)
displacy.render(doc, style="dep")

# Check whether preposition applies to verb or object
prep = [token for token in doc if token.text == 'with'][0]
print(f"'{prep.text}' applies to '{prep.head.text}'")
```

[image: Dependency tree diagram for the 1st example sentence]

Instead of "use the key to unlock the door" it has interpreted the sentence as meaning "unlock the door that has a key".

In most cases it gets it right as in this example:

```
# Example 2 - finds correct dependency tree
sent = "unlock the door with the key"
doc = nlp(sent)
displacy.render(doc, style="dep")

# Check whether preposition applies to verb or object
prep = [token for token in doc if token.text == 'with'][0]
print(f"'{prep.text}' applies to '{prep.head.text}'")
```

[image: Dependency tree diagram for the 2nd example sentence]
What I would like is to have it return all (or at least the two most likely) possible dependency trees so I can analyse both and decide which one is correct based on other information.  I seem to recall this was possible in NLTK.